# ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos) постоянно выводит одно и тоже значение

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

    Debug.Log(worldPos);

}
```

Постоянно выводит (-4.0, 2.5, 0.0) даже когда курсор меняет местоположение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScreenToWorldPoint` принимает на вход параметр типа `Vector3`. `Input.mousePosition` возвращает `Vector2`. Вы в первой строчке неявно преобразовываете `Vector2` к `Vector3`, а в результате такого преобразования z-координата по умолчанию присваивается `0.0`. В методе `ScreenToWorldPoint` z-координата означает расстояние от камеры. Скорее всего, получается так, что позиция мыши (с учетом `z = 0.0`) не попадает в область видимости камеры, по этому то, что вы видите в консоли - `(-4.0, 2.5, 0.0)`- могут быть координаты камеры.

Чтобы метод возвращал интересующее вас значение, попробуйте не просто неявно преобразовывать `Vector2` к `Vector3`, а руками прописывать туда какую-нибудь z-координату, которая попадет в область видимости камеры, исправив код:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    //если не поможет это значение, подставьте значение больше, 
    //которое точно будет внутри видимости камеры
    mousePos.z = 5.0f; 
    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

    Debug.Log(worldPos);
}
```

Update: Как верно указали в комментарии, можно использовать в качестве z-координаты `Camera.main.nearClipPlane`, вместо случайной константы.

Comment: Рандомное расстояние от камеры - плохо, лучше уж хотя бы плоскости отсечения использовать: `mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Абсолютно согласен. дополнил ответ

Comment: Вот теперь имхо ответ самодостаточен и максимально просто и правильно отвечает на вопрос :)